# compiling and rendering complex Dust.js templates on the client

Tags: javascript, dust.js, kraken.js

I'm trying to compile and render a Dust template on the fly with nested partials from the client, but I keep getting "Error: Template Not Found: [templatePath]". The example shown below works if I use a child template that doesn't reference any partials (e.g. /templates/includes/childTemplate.dust), but not from a higher level main template (e.g. /templates/main.dust). Is there a way to pre-compile high level templates with child partials included?

```
var model = { ... };

$.get('/templates/main.dust', function(tpl) {
    var compiled = dust.compile(tpl, 'mainTemplate');

    dust.loadSource(compiled);
    dust.render('mainTemplate', model, function(err, output) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        $('#target').html(output);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dust partials are resolved at render time, not compile time, so there's no way to precompile into a master template.

Instead, Dust provides a way for you to tell it how to load additional templates through the use of the `dust.onLoad` function.

```
dust.onLoad = function(templateName, callback) {
  // naive jQuery loading of a new template
  $.get('/templates/' + templateName + '.dust', function(data) {
    callback(null, data);
  });
};
```

If you need to compile the template after you receive it, pass it as the second parameter to `callback` and Dust will compile it. If you're loading precompiled templates, just evaluate the precompiled template by calling `dust.loadSource(data)` and then call `callback()`.

You'll likely want to bake in a template precompilation step to your workflow, perhaps using the `dustc` compiler that's included with Dust, so you don't have to compile on the client (it's slow, and you have to include `dust-full.js` instead of `dust-core.js`).

You might consider loading Dust and its templates as AMD modules. See http://www.dustjs.com/guides/setup/#amd . If you do this Dust will wire up the `onLoad` for you automatically by using `require`.

The Dust repo has some basic examples of different ways you can handle Dust in the browser. See [examples/basic-browser](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tree/master/examples/basic-browser) and [examples/amd](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tree/master/examples/amd).

Comment: Thanks, your example worked great for the simple mock I was working on. Per your recommendation I ultimately ended up pre-compiling to AMD modules, pre-loading core templates through requirejs, and loading optional ones on demand.

Comment: Nice. That's a new feature so definitely let us know how it works for you. Improvements are coming so that you can pass the template directly to dust.render instead of its name.